# Variable length data in an array

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating an apps script that will allow a teacher to copy and paste their grades into a google spreadsheet and will calculate student averages for HW, CW, Labs, and Tests.  It will then take those final 4 weighted categories and calculate the students final average.  They key, is that the number of HW, CW, Labs, and Tests are dynamic.       Today, there could be 5 homework assignments, but tomorrow, there could be 7, and next week 10.  Same with the other three categories.  At the end, the script will merge the information into a document template and then email the grades.
I have the completed the portion with doing the grading part and now I am on to the document merge part and am not to sure what to search for for help on stackoverflow. Under normal situations in which the number of columns are fixed, such as form input, I can do a document merge and then email the document. You get the values for the array and define variables for each column

```
var data = sh.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastCol).getValues();
var stufirstname = data[0][1];
var stulastname = data[0][2];
and so on an so forth
```

.getRange(Row,Column,numRow,numCol).getValues(); is dynamic so how do I pull the information out of it? I am looking to get something like the following to work.

```
var hw1 = data[0][1]
var hw2 = data[0][2]
var hw3 = data[0][3]
```

Like I said earlier, next week there could be more homework assignments so I would have to change the script to get the other assignments for the document merge. I do have the user entering the number of HW assignments so while it is dynamic, it is known by the script.  Any ideas?  This may be easy but I have not been able to find anything.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific with exactly what you're trying to do. Maybe use an example spreadsheet and explain what part you're getting stuck on. Also use a better code example.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit awkward since the layout of your data sheet is unknown. Here's how I'd approach it; hopefully it will give you a head start:

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var students = ss.getSheetByName('Students');
    var grades = ss.getSheetByName('Grades');
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.GetUi();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var flow = app.createFlowPanel();
    var categoryArray = ['Homework', 'Classwork', 'Labs', 'Tests'];
    var categoryList = app.createListBox().setId('categoryList');
    for (i=0;i<categoryArray.length;i++) {categoryList.addItem(categoryArray[i], categoryArray[i])}
    var studentArray = [];
    var studentValues = students.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (i=0;i<students.getLastRow();i++) {studentArray.push(studentValues[i][firstNameColumnInt] + ' ' + studentValues[i][lastNameColumnInt]);}
    var studentList = app.createListBox().setId('student');
    for (i=0;i<studentArray.length;i++) {studentList.addItem(studentArray[i], categoryArray[i])};
    var grade = app.createTextBox().setId('grade');    
    var submit = app.createButton('Submit Grade');
    var report = app.createButton('Report Student Averages');

    var submitHandler = app.createServerHandler('submitHandler').addCallbackElement(flow);
    var reportHandler = app.createServerHandler('reportHandler').addCallbackElement(flow);

    submit.addClickHandler(submitHandler);
    report.addClickHandler(reportHandler);

    flow.add(studentList).add(categoryList).add(submit).add(report);

    app.add(flow);

    ui.showSidebar(app);

}
```

// I'm making some assumption about how you log grades.
// Using this system will dynamically code each entry by name, category, grade & timestamp

```
function submitHandler (e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var app = UiApp.getActive();
    var grades = ss.getSheetByName('Grades');

    grades.appendRow([e.parameter.student, e.parameter.category, e.parameter.grade, new Date()]);

    return app;

}

// 
function reportHandler (e) {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var app = UiApp.getActive();
    var students = ss.getSheetByName('Students');
    var studentArray = [];
    var studentValues = students.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (i=0;i<students.getLastRow();i++) {studentArray.push(studentValues[i][firstNameColumnInt] + ' ' + studentValues[i][lastNameColumnInt]);}
    var body = DocumentApp.create('Report').getBody();
    var title = body.appendParagraph('Student Grades Report Generated: ' + new Date());
    var table = body.appendTable().appendTableRow(['Name', 'Category Averages 1 - 4 (or n)', 'Grade');
    for (i=0;i<students.getLastRow();i++) {
        body.appendRow([studentArray[i], yourWeightedAverageFormulaForAGivenCategory(i), yourGPAFormula(i)])}
        }

    GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 'Generated Report', body);

    app.close();
    return app;
}
```

Anyway, I know this code is incomplete, but hopefully there's enough here to get you on the right path (and maybe earn me some S.O. points...) While the number of items per category changes, you can arrive at a divisor programmatically by COUNTing the number of category codes  between two timestamps (week start/end, or whatever) inside the Grades sheet.